# Is there a way to fix splash screen interaction with code and avoid crashing?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I'm setting up this android Bluetooth app using android studio and I'm having trouble getting the splash screen to show properly and then transition with the program. What would I need to do in order to have my main and splash screen working together without the program crashing?

I have tried manipulating the manifest to get the main GUI and the splash screen to work together but usually only one of them works, followed by a crash of the app. I'm currently using the latest version of Android Studio and have revised the splash screen multiple times, but believe the main problem has to do with the manifest.

### AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.harbit">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <application

        <activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BT">          </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BTGU">        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".REC" >        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

### Splash screen java code

```
   package com.example.harbit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent Intent = new Intent(Splash.this, BTGU.class);
                startActivity(Intent);

            }
        },4000);

    }
}
```

I expect the app to correctly display the splash screen followed by the display of the general user interface without the program crashing.
/////////////////////////////////////////
this are all the errors coming from the Logcat after the app crashes.

```
2019-04-05 12:13:55.395 8028-8028/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.harbit, PID: 8028
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.harbit/com.example.harbit.BTGU}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3987)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4019)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.<init>(BluetoothDevice.java:1176)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter.java:917)
        at com.example.harbit.BTGU.onResume(BTGU.java:125)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3979)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4019) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////
BTGU Activity
//////////////////////////////

```
package com.example.harbit;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BTGU extends AppCompatActivity {

    //1)
    ImageButton IdListen, IdRecord,IdFiles,IdDisconect;
    TextView IdBPM;
    //-------------------------------------------
    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder DataStringIN = new StringBuilder();
    private ConnectedThread MyConexionBT;
    // Unique identifier of service - SPP UUID
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    // String for MAC address
    private static String address = null;
    //-------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_btgu);
        //Link buttons to on click listeners
        IdListen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IdListen);
        IdRecord = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IdRecord);
        IdFiles = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IdFiles);
        IdDisconect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IdDisconect);
        IdBPM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IdBPM);

        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                    int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                        String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                        IdBPM.setText("BPM: " + dataInPrint);
                        DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get Bluetooth adapter
        VerifyBT();

        // setup onClick listeners for the buttons
        // to indicate the following active after activation
        // of the onclick event
        // as an RXTX event
        IdListen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MyConexionBT.write("1");
            }
        });

        IdRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyConexionBT.write("2");
            }
        });

        IdFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
              //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>>>>>
            }
        });

        IdDisconect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (btSocket!=null)
                {
                    try {btSocket.close();}
                    catch (IOException e)
                    { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;}
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException
    {
        //Safe exit removal of the device
        //using service UUID
        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //get the MAC address from DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //get the MAC address from DeviceListActivity via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(BT.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        //Set the MAC address
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try
        {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // establish connection with Bluetooth socket.
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {}
        }
        MyConexionBT = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        MyConexionBT.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        try
        { // when out of the app this allows for the closing of the socket
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {}
    }

    //check the device bluetooth and if off pop a message to turn it on
    private void VerifyBT() {

        if(btAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //Create the class that enables the event of connectivity
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread
    {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try
            {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }
// set up Rx for incoming data
        public void run()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Begin listen mode to determine the incoming data
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained data to the event via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //String TX to the receiving device
        public void write(String input)
        {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(input.getBytes());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //If TX not available close connectivity
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put log here when app crashes ?we need to figure it out why your app crashes. and trying to fix it.

Comment: you should also put finish() in the splashActivity. But for us to understand it better put the error logs in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should correct your app AndroidManifest file. It can be the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.harbit">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

 <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BTGU"/>
    <activity android:name=".BTGU"/>
    <activity android:name=".REC"/>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

And your splash activity can be:

```
package com.example.harbit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, BTGU.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP 
                  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK 
                  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    },4000);

  }
}
```

Comment: the part of the code you added in the splash activity seems to have some errors               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK                      this part needs a semicolon but still doesnt work 
| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                  although this seems the same syntax as the intent flag above they are not the same and even when matched the program doesnt recognize them as functions

Comment: It does not need any semicolon. Please run the code without putting any semicolon.  And add your error here.

Comment: Please share the code of BTGU activity. Problem is in BTGU activity actually.

Comment: I have added the code for BTGU (Bluetooth general user interface)

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.<init>(BluetoothDevice.java:1176)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter.java:917)
        at com.example.harbit.BTGU.onResume(BTGU.java:125)
```

You are getting an extra that is not passed from the previous activity

```
        //This is null you never add the extra on the Splash
        address = intent.getStringExtra(BT.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
         //This is crashing, the address is null
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
```

On SplashActivity you have to

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(Splash.this, BTGU.class);
//I dont know how you plan to obatained the address
intent.putExtra(BT.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, "A VALID ADDRESS");
startActivity(Intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve extra through intent in BTGU activity but you did not send it from SplashActivity activity. You should add the following code in SplashActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, BTGU.class);
intent.putExtra(BT.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, getMacAddress());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP 
              | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK 
              | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

You can get MAC address through the following method or try your own method to get mac address :

```
private String getMacAddress(){
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    String bluetoothMacAddress = "";
    try {
        Field mServiceField = bluetoothAdapter.getClass().getDeclaredField("mService");
        mServiceField.setAccessible(true);

        Object btManagerService = mServiceField.get(bluetoothAdapter);

        if (btManagerService != null) {
            bluetoothMacAddress = (String) btManagerService.getClass().getMethod("getAddress").invoke(btManagerService);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ignore) {

    }
    return bluetoothMacAddress;
}
```

Comment: Would getting the MAC address through your method apply even though I'm not using WIFI and the device im trying to connect will not be using wifi

Comment: Edited. You can try now.

Comment: now it skips one of the activities for selecting the paired Bluetooth devices, instead of allowing you to select  a device a white screen skips this step and goes directly into the control screen.

Comment: with the wifi MAC address method it crashed after pressing any of the buttons, and with this new method it crashes after the splash screen just like before